# How to transfer GitHub classroom private repo to my GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, github-classroom

I have an assignment project which was created by GitHub Classroom and is also private. So how to transfer my project to my personal account with all existing commits?

Answer (score 2):

[Step 1]

1. Go to Github classroom private repo and clone the git URL from [code]
2. Open cmd from the parent folder
3. `git clone --bare _____(clone URL)` [--bare => clone with all commits]
4. open the cloned folder from explorer

[Step 2]

1. Create a new repo
2. Just copy the origin URL
3. `git push --mirror _____(origin url)` [--mirror => transfer all commits]

[Step 3]

1. Change origin [otherwise new code will push to the previous git location]
2. `git remote -v`[checking remote version]
3. `git remote set-url origin _____(origin URL)`
4. `git remote -v`

Examples

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/your-assignment-project.git

git push --mirror https://github.com/your-personal-repo.git

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your-personal-repo.git

git remote -v
```